# How to add a layered navigation on a custom product catalog on Magento 2.4

Tags: layered-navigation, custom-pages, magento2.4

I need to add a custom page as 'Offers' on my client site with layered navigation.
I need to fetch product collection by its attributes 'is_offer_on' and show them on the page.

Most of the answers and topics I found in the internet are either outdated (Magento 1.x or 2.0) or confusing due to  missing bits and pieces here and there. I really would appreciate if someone could point out the steps or a tutorial which explains what exactly needs to be done on achieving this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any suggestions please?

Comment: did you find any sollution?

Comment: HI bro,@Mujahidh, good to see you here. Yes. found one article on how to do it. 
http://www.wishusucess.com/how-to-filter-products-by-attribute-in-magento-2/

Comment: hi Thank you, OMG now only noticed its you :)